# Unable to create Dataproc cluster on Google Cloud Platform "NodeInitializationAction must specify executable"

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataproc, airflow-scheduler

Facing below error while creating Dataproc Cluster on Google Cloud Platform. We are using Mercury plugin for Airflow. Just want to understand like what is the issue. I tried many options but till now I could not reach any conclusion.

```
[2020-03-26 06:04:14,612] {base_task_runner.py:95} INFO - Subtask: [2020-03-26 06:04:14,612] {models.py:1352} INFO - Executing <Task(GoogleCloudCreateDataprocCluster): create_medax_cluster> on 2020-03-26 06:03:40.963562
[2020-03-26 06:04:14,649] {base_task_runner.py:95} INFO - Subtask: [2020-03-26 06:04:14,649] {gcp_api_base_hook.py:73} INFO - Getting connection using `gcloud auth` user, since no key file is defined for hook.
[2020-03-26 06:04:14,655] {base_task_runner.py:95} INFO - Subtask: [2020-03-26 06:04:14,655] {discovery.py:267} INFO - URL being requested: GET https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/dataproc/v1beta2/rest
[2020-03-26 06:04:14,655] {base_task_runner.py:95} INFO - Subtask: [2020-03-26 06:04:14,655] {transport.py:157} INFO - Attempting refresh to obtain initial access_token
[2020-03-26 06:04:14,732] {base_task_runner.py:95} INFO - Subtask: [2020-03-26 06:04:14,731] {discovery.py:866} INFO - URL being requested: GET https://dataproc.googleapis.com/v1beta2/projects/dh-xxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxx-72410/regions/xxxxxxxx/clusters?alt=json
[2020-03-26 06:04:15,455] {base_task_runner.py:95} INFO - Subtask: File gs://xxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxx-dpl-artif/dataproc/dataproc-init.sh will not be executed on dataproc startup.
[2020-03-26 06:04:15,455] {base_task_runner.py:95} INFO - Subtask: [2020-03-26 06:04:15,455] {discovery.py:866} INFO - URL being requested: POST https://dataproc.googleapis.com/v1beta2/projects/dh-xxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxx-72410/regions/xxxxxxxx/clusters?alt=json
[2020-03-26 06:04:20,490] {base_task_runner.py:95} INFO - Subtask: [2020-03-26 06:04:20,490] {discovery.py:866} INFO - URL being requested: GET https://dataproc.googleapis.com/v1beta2/projects/dh-xxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxx-72410/regions/xxxxxxxx/clusters?alt=json
[2020-03-26 06:04:20,534] {base_task_runner.py:95} INFO - Subtask: [2020-03-26 06:04:20,533] {models.py:1427} ERROR - <HttpError 400 when requesting https://dataproc.googleapis.com/v1beta2/projects/dh-xxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxx-72410/regions/xxxxxxxx/clusters?alt=json returned "Multiple validation errors:
[2020-03-26 06:04:20,535] {base_task_runner.py:95} INFO - Subtask:  - NodeInitializationAction must specify executable
[2020-03-26 06:04:20,535] {base_task_runner.py:95} INFO - Subtask:  - Object URI '' is not a valid GCS URI">
[2020-03-26 06:04:20,535] {base_task_runner.py:95} INFO - Subtask: Traceback (most recent call last):
[2020-03-26 06:04:20,535] {base_task_runner.py:95} INFO - Subtask:   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/airflow/models.py", line 1384, in run
[2020-03-26 06:04:20,535] {base_task_runner.py:95} INFO - Subtask:     result = task_copy.execute(context=context)
[2020-03-26 06:04:20,535] {base_task_runner.py:95} INFO - Subtask:   File "/usr/local/airflow/plugins/mercury_plugins.py", line 1516, in execute
[2020-03-26 06:04:20,535] {base_task_runner.py:95} INFO - Subtask:     raise e
[2020-03-26 06:04:20,536] {base_task_runner.py:95} INFO - Subtask: HttpError: <HttpError 400 when requesting https://dataproc.googleapis.com/v1beta2/projects/dh-xxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxx-72410/regions/xxxxxxxx/clusters?alt=json returned "Multiple validation errors:
[2020-03-26 06:04:20,536] {base_task_runner.py:95} INFO - Subtask:  - NodeInitializationAction must specify executable
[2020-03-26 06:04:20,536] {base_task_runner.py:95} INFO - Subtask:  - Object URI '' is not a valid GCS URI">
[2020-03-26 06:04:20,536] {base_task_runner.py:95} INFO - Subtask: [2020-03-26 06:04:20,534] {models.py:1451} INFO - Marking task as FAILED.
[2020-03-26 06:04:20,537] {base_task_runner.py:95} INFO - Subtask: [2020-03-26 06:04:20,537] {configuration.py:609} WARNING - section/key [smtp/smtp_user] not found in config
[2020-03-26 06:04:20,538] {base_task_runner.py:95} INFO - Subtask: [2020-03-26 06:04:20,538] {models.py:1466} ERROR - Failed at executing callback
[2020-03-26 06:04:20,539] {base_task_runner.py:95} INFO - Subtask: [2020-03-26 06:04:20,538] {models.py:1467} ERROR - [Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address
[2020-03-26 06:04:20,539] {base_task_runner.py:95} INFO - Subtask: Traceback (most recent call last):
[2020-03-26 06:04:20,539] {base_task_runner.py:95} INFO - Subtask:   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/airflow/models.py", line 1464, in handle_failure
[2020-03-26 06:04:20,539] {base_task_runner.py:95} INFO - Subtask:     task.on_failure_callback(context)
[2020-03-26 06:04:20,539] {base_task_runner.py:95} INFO - Subtask:   File "/usr/local/airflow/dags/notification.py", line 35, in on_failure_callback
[2020-03-26 06:04:20,539] {base_task_runner.py:95} INFO - Subtask:     return operator.execute(context=context)
[2020-03-26 06:04:20,540] {base_task_runner.py:95} INFO - Subtask:   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/airflow/operators/email_operator.py", line 64, in execute
[2020-03-26 06:04:20,540] {base_task_runner.py:95} INFO - Subtask:     send_email(self.to, self.subject, self.html_content, files=self.files, cc=self.cc, bcc=self.bcc, mime_subtype=self.mime_subtype)
[2020-03-26 06:04:20,540] {base_task_runner.py:95} INFO - Subtask:   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/airflow/utils/email.py", line 44, in send_email
[2020-03-26 06:04:20,540] {base_task_runner.py:95} INFO - Subtask:     return backend(to, subject, html_content, files=files, dryrun=dryrun, cc=cc, bcc=bcc, mime_subtype=mime_subtype)
[2020-03-26 06:04:20,540] {base_task_runner.py:95} INFO - Subtask:   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/airflow/utils/email.py", line 86, in send_email_smtp
[2020-03-26 06:04:20,541] {base_task_runner.py:95} INFO - Subtask:     send_MIME_email(SMTP_MAIL_FROM, recipients, msg, dryrun)
[2020-03-26 06:04:20,541] {base_task_runner.py:95} INFO - Subtask:   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/airflow/utils/email.py", line 104, in send_MIME_email
[2020-03-26 06:04:20,541] {base_task_runner.py:95} INFO - Subtask:     s = smtplib.SMTP_SSL(SMTP_HOST, SMTP_PORT) if SMTP_SSL else smtplib.SMTP(SMTP_HOST, SMTP_PORT)
[2020-03-26 06:04:20,541] {base_task_runner.py:95} INFO - Subtask:   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 256, in __init__
[2020-03-26 06:04:20,542] {base_task_runner.py:95} INFO - Subtask:     (code, msg) = self.connect(host, port)
[2020-03-26 06:04:20,542] {base_task_runner.py:95} INFO - Subtask:   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 316, in connect
[2020-03-26 06:04:20,542] {base_task_runner.py:95} INFO - Subtask:     self.sock = self._get_socket(host, port, self.timeout)
[2020-03-26 06:04:20,542] {base_task_runner.py:95} INFO - Subtask:   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 291, in _get_socket
[2020-03-26 06:04:20,542] {base_task_runner.py:95} INFO - Subtask:     return socket.create_connection((host, port), timeout)
[2020-03-26 06:04:20,543] {base_task_runner.py:95} INFO - Subtask:   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 575, in create_connection
[2020-03-26 06:04:20,543] {base_task_runner.py:95} INFO - Subtask:     raise err
[2020-03-26 06:04:20,543] {base_task_runner.py:95} INFO - Subtask: error: [Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address
[2020-03-26 06:04:20,553] {base_task_runner.py:95} INFO - Subtask: [2020-03-26 06:04:20,553] {models.py:1472} ERROR - <HttpError 400 when requesting https://dataproc.googleapis.com/v1beta2/projects/dh-xxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxx-72410/regions/xxxxxxxx/clusters?alt=json returned "Multiple validation errors:
[2020-03-26 06:04:20,553] {base_task_runner.py:95} INFO - Subtask:  - NodeInitializationAction must specify executable
[2020-03-26 06:04:20,554] {base_task_runner.py:95} INFO - Subtask:  - Object URI '' is not a valid GCS URI">
[2020-03-26 06:04:20,554] {base_task_runner.py:95} INFO - Subtask: Traceback (most recent call last):
[2020-03-26 06:04:20,554] {base_task_runner.py:95} INFO - Subtask:   File "/usr/local/bin/airflow", line 28, in <module>
[2020-03-26 06:04:20,554] {base_task_runner.py:95} INFO - Subtask:     args.func(args)
[2020-03-26 06:04:20,554] {base_task_runner.py:95} INFO - Subtask:   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/airflow/bin/cli.py", line 422, in run
[2020-03-26 06:04:20,554] {base_task_runner.py:95} INFO - Subtask:     pool=args.pool,
[2020-03-26 06:04:20,555] {base_task_runner.py:95} INFO - Subtask:   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/airflow/utils/db.py", line 53, in wrapper
[2020-03-26 06:04:20,555] {base_task_runner.py:95} INFO - Subtask:     result = func(*args, **kwargs)
[2020-03-26 06:04:20,555] {base_task_runner.py:95} INFO - Subtask:   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/airflow/models.py", line 1384, in run
[2020-03-26 06:04:20,555] {base_task_runner.py:95} INFO - Subtask:     result = task_copy.execute(context=context)
[2020-03-26 06:04:20,555] {base_task_runner.py:95} INFO - Subtask:   File "/usr/local/airflow/plugins/mercury_plugins.py", line 1516, in execute
[2020-03-26 06:04:20,555] {base_task_runner.py:95} INFO - Subtask:     raise e
[2020-03-26 06:04:20,556] {base_task_runner.py:95} INFO - Subtask: googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 400 when requesting https://dataproc.googleapis.com/v1beta2/projects/dh-xxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxx-72410/regions/xxxxxxxx/clusters?alt=json returned "Multiple validation errors:
[2020-03-26 06:04:20,556] {base_task_runner.py:95} INFO - Subtask:  - NodeInitializationAction must specify executable
[2020-03-26 06:04:20,556] {base_task_runner.py:95} INFO - Subtask:  - Object URI '' is not a valid GCS URI">
[2020-03-26 06:04:22,646] {jobs.py:2107} INFO - Task exited with return code 1
```

I tried changing name of cluster. But that did not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issues is that you specified an empty path for [initialization action](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/concepts/configuring-clusters/init-actions) in Airflow workflow:

```
INFO - Subtask:  - Object URI '' is not a valid GCS URI">
```

Here is an example how you should do it using [DataprocClusterCreateOperator](https://airflow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/_api/airflow/contrib/operators/dataproc_operator/index.html#airflow.contrib.operators.dataproc_operator.DataprocClusterCreateOperator) in Airflow:

```py
DataprocClusterCreateOperator(
    # ...
    init_actions_uris = ['gs://<BUCKET>/path/to/init/action.sh'],
    # ...
)
```

If you are not using initialization actions, then you should not set `init_actions_uris` parameter at all, or you should set it to `None`.

Comment: Thanks, You are right.  Actually i gave it like "init_actions_uris = [task_config.get("init_actions_uris", None)]", and I thought it will pic the default script when i don't init_actions_uris variable.  But that was not the case. it became null some how.